# how to replace missing date from NAT to some date in increasing order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a date column

[image]

the missing values(NAT in python) needs to be incremented in loop with one day 
that is 1/1/2015 , 1/2/2016, 1/3/2016

Can any one help me out ?

Comment: Don't post images. Provide data in text.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar if I have date as 12/29/2014, 12/30/2014, 12/30/2015.

next 4 as NAT's ,

the next 4 NAt's should get replaced with Increase order per 1 day

like  1/1/2015 , 1/2/2016, 1/3/2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add an incremental date to your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

ddict = {
    'Date': ['2014-12-29','2014-12-30','2014-12-31','','','','',]
    }

data = pd.DataFrame(ddict)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

def fill_dates(data_frame, date_col='Date'):
    ### Seconds in a day (3600 seconds per hour x 24 hours per day)
    day_s = 3600 * 24

    ### Create datetime variable for adding 1 day
    _day = dt.timedelta(seconds=day_s)

    ### Get the max non-null date
    max_dt = data_frame[date_col].max()

    ### Get index of missing date values
    NaT_index = data_frame[data_frame[date_col].isnull()].index

    ### Loop through index; Set incremental date value; Increment variable by 1 day
    for i in NaT_index:
        data_frame[date_col][i] = max_dt + _day
        _day += dt.timedelta(seconds=day_s)

### Execute function
fill_dates(data, 'Date')
```

Initial data frame:

```
        Date
0 2014-12-29
1 2014-12-30
2 2014-12-31
3        NaT
4        NaT
5        NaT
6        NaT
```

After running the function:

```
        Date
0 2014-12-29
1 2014-12-30
2 2014-12-31
3 2015-01-01
4 2015-01-02
5 2015-01-03
6 2015-01-04
```